# Perl Net::Stripe Internal Server Error with Bad Credit Card Number

Tags: perl, stripe-payments

I am using Net::Stripe to process credit cards. It is working correctly if the credit card number is valid. But when I test a bad credit card number, I get to line 676 of Stripe.pm:

```
676:        die $e;
```

and that produces this error:

> 1 at /usr/share/perl/5.14/perl5db.pl line 7799.

which causes an Internal Server Error in the browser.

The block of code in Stripe.pm that ends with the die statement is this:

```
if ($resp->code == 200) {
    return _hash_to_object(decode_json($resp->content));
} elsif ($resp->code == 500) {
    die Net::Stripe::Error->new(
        type => "HTTP request error",
        code => $resp->code,
        message => $resp->status_line . " - " . $resp->content,
    );
}

my $e = eval {
    my $hash = decode_json($resp->content);
    Net::Stripe::Error->new($hash->{error})
};
if ($@) {
    Net::Stripe::Error->new(
        type => "Could not decode HTTP response: $@",
        message => $resp->status_line . " - " . $resp->content,
    );
};

warn "$e\n" if $self->debug;
die $e;
```

The response code that is being returned from Stripe is 402.

I am trying to handle error messages from Stripe with the following code:

```
my $card_token = $stripe->post_token(
    card => {
        number    => $FORM{'Credit Card #'},
        exp_month => $FORM{'Expiration Month'},
        exp_year  => $FORM{'Expiration Year'},
        currency  => 'usd',
        cvc       => $FORM{'Credit Card Security Code'},
        name      => $FORM{'Name on Card'},
        address_line1  => $FORM{'Address'},
        address_city  => $FORM{'City'},
        address_state  => $FORM{'State'},
        address_zip  => $FORM{'Zip'}
    }
);

if ($card_token->{failure_message}) {

    $error = $card_token->{failure_message};

    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
    print "There was an error processing your credit card:<br><br>$error";

}
```

But the code is dying before it exits the block of code that is trying to retrieve the token.

Is there a way to suppress that "die" statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) to trap this exception, then carry on working.

```
my $card_token;

my $ok = eval {
    $card_token = $stripe->post_token(
        card => {
            number    => $FORM{'Credit Card #'},
            exp_month => $FORM{'Expiration Month'},
            exp_year  => $FORM{'Expiration Year'},
            currency  => 'usd',
            cvc       => $FORM{'Credit Card Security Code'},
            name      => $FORM{'Name on Card'},
            address_line1  => $FORM{'Address'},
            address_city  => $FORM{'City'},
            address_state  => $FORM{'State'},
            address_zip  => $FORM{'Zip'}
        }
    );

    1;
}

if (! $ok) {
    # error object is in $@. You'll need to investigate its structure
    # before using it

    my $error = $@;

    ...;
}
else {
    # do stuff with $card_token
}
```